# Difference between ByteBuffer.allocateDirect() and glGenBuffers()

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

What is difference between `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()` and `glGenBuffers()`? Why we use on android `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()` instead of `glGenBuffers()` like in classic OpenGL?

Comment: Since the two functions are in no way equivalent or comperable, I'm not sure I understand your question. Even if you meant `glBufferData`, they're still not that similar. And the differences seem pretty obvious: one is an OpenGL object, the other is a Java object.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, thanks. But why in every basic OpenGL Tutorial for rendering triangle is used OpenGL object and in every Android OpenGL ES tutorial for rendering triangle is used java object instead of OpenGL object? For example: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tutorial:_OpenGL_3.1_The_First_Triangle_(C%2B%2B/Win)  and https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/shapes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But why in every basic OpenGL Tutorial for rendering triangle is used OpenGL object and in every Android OpenGL ES tutorial for rendering triangle is used java object instead of OpenGL object?

Because they can.

`ByteBuffer` represents a CPU memory allocation. An OpenGL buffer object represents a *GPU*-accessible memory allocation.

OpenGL ES 2.0 allows users to specify vertex data from either CPU memory or buffer objects. Desktop core OpenGL *removed* this ability since 2009. So modern desktop OpenGL tutorials use buffer objects for vertex data.

Note that ES 3.0 explicitly says that "client-side vertex arrays":

> are  present  to  maintain  backward  compatibility  with OpenGL ES 2.0, but their use in not recommended as it is likely for these features to be removed in a future version.

They haven't been removed yet. But they do interfere with a number of features. For example, they make `gl_VertexID` undefined.

So you should never use `ByteBuffer` directly for vertex arrays. And you should avoid learning materials that do so, as they may teach you other bad practices.